# How to set svg print (in mm for CorelDraw) and real/preview (in px) sizes?

Tags: javascript, web, svg, coreldraw

I have a basic SVG file, that has a fix 50mm x 25mm print size (so if I open it with CorelDraw the document size will be this.)

```
<svg 
    width=50mm
    height=25mm
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
>
    <g>
        <text
            x=0
            y=55
            font-family="Verdana"
            font-size=55
            fill="black"
        >NOS?</text>
        <line
            class='v_pos'
            stroke="green"  
            x1=0 
            y1=55 
            x2=500
            y2=55
            stroke-width="1"  
        />
    </g>
</svg>
```

How can I achieve 500x250 px size in the browser? The ratio does not change, but I need a fixed canvas size in the web-browser too.

I need reword/extend the problem:

I'd like to export the graphics (created in browser) to CorelDraw, as it can read SVG files. The canvas in browser is for example 500x250px, and every object are measured first in pixel. After the export everything must be resided, **started from the canvas** (to 50x25mm) followed by the objects:

[image: I need to set this]

So the questions are:

- witch attribute is responsible for canvas width and height in CorelDraw?
- is there any fast way (preserveAspectRatio, viewBox, style media) of resizing containing objects, or I have to convert every object's width,height,x,y, etc. attributes one by one?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different *size* aspects of a SVG image: how much do you want to see from the infinite canvas, and how big should the resulting image be. The first one is defined by the `viewBox`, which contains *x* and *y* coordinates for the top-left corner, and a *width* and a *height*. The second one is defined using the `width` and `height` attributes or style properties.

So, you use the `viewBox` attribute to say that you're interested in the area inside the `(0px, 0px)` and `(500px, 250px)` rectangle, since that is what you see in the browser: `viewBox="0 0 500 250"`

Then, since you want the image to be displayed as `50mm` wide and `25mm` high, you set the width and height accordingly. You can do that either setting them as attributes on the root svg element, which means that you have to set them only when exporting, since otherwise they will apply in the browser as well, or you can set them using a `style` element valid only for `print` media.

For browsers, if you're defining the `viewBox` you don't need to specify the width and height explicitly, since by default the area defined in the viewBox is displayed pixel per pixel.

Comment: I have made a test: http://jsbin.com/azapof/1/edit , where the screen size does not much. `:(`

Comment: Because when you embed the SVG in a HTML document, it' no longer a `:root` element. Just remove the `:root` part from the CSS selector to make it work.

Comment: If I open the created SVG with Corel Draw the objects sizes are great but it is placed in the middle of a 210x197mm (A4) large paper. Is it possible to resize that too (as the image in my question shows)?

Comment: I don't know how Corel Draw handles the canvas (paper) size. You could try to see how it does it by exporting a SVG file with some specified dimensions and look in the file to see where those dimensions are set. I don't have Corel Draw, so I can't check myself.

Comment: I have tired it and Corel Draw does not save these properties into SVG file. (If I open the exported file, the settings will be lost.)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with different *media*, use stylesheet *media selectors*. And SVG has support for that natively, using the [`media` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleElementMediaAttribute) of the `<style>` element. The basic syntax would be:

```
<style media="something" type="text/css">
  svg:root {
    width: 50mm;
    height: 25mm; 
  }
</style>
```

Now, depending on what you want to do, you can:

1. Use `media="print"` to specify the size for print media, letting the default width and height specified in the attributes set on the root `<svg>` element be used in all other cases
2. Use `media="screen"` to specify the target width and height just for browsers when using a *screen* to display, where *screen* is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types) as: "Intended primarily for color computer screens".

Comment: I have extended my question, please take a look at that!